# AWS Cognito cross region replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, replication, disaster-recovery

This is one of the biggest problems for cognito as there doesnt seem to be a direct way to have cross region replication for disaster recovery. Has anyone found a work around for having cognito user pools replicate to another region and make it as seamless for the end user as possible

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/cognito-user-profiles-export-reference-architecture/

Comment: @MarkB thank you, do you know if this replicates the uuid of the user(known in cognito as sub)

Comment: This is not really a replication but a copy of some of the attributes. There will be a new user pool with new users having new UUIDs and no passwords

Comment: and do you happen to know if there is a way to replicate them with the same UUIDs ?

Comment: @PabloArriola that would be interesting to me as well, did you find a solution here?

Comment: @tobias just to update you, i did not find a way to do it, at least not having the same UUID for the clients. AWS has also not released any updates